# How to populate Picker items before open, using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin.Forms, how do I populate a `Picker` with items, immediately before the `Picker` opens?

We have a number of pickers on the same page and it would be inefficient to populate all items upfront, as some of the queries are expensive.  For reference, I'm trying to get this working on Xamarin.Android first, and am using the latest stable version - 1.2.36257 at the time of writing.

I've tried:

- `Focused` event - This almost works, but changes to `Items` are not applied until the next time the `Picker` opens.
- TapGestureRecognizer - The `Tapped` event doesn't seem to be fired.  Perhaps it doesn't work with a `Picker`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that the **Xamarin.Forms** **Picker** exposes from what I can see either, that would allow you to achieve what your wanting.

**TapGesture**'s can be troublesome.  For instance I quickly tried it on **WindowsPhone**, and that is not recognizing the **TapGesture** either.  Your also find some different behavior with different controls as well - with the same response not being uniform across platforms.

I tried hooking into the **Picker** **PropertyChanged** / **PropertyChanging**, and this has the outcome exactly the same as attempting to hook into the **Focused** event handler that you experienced, with it only working after the picker has initially been displayed.

The only way around this would be to write a custom renderer to achieve what you want to do.

Within that, you could then expose custom events such as OnBeforeAppearing, that would allow you to then pre-load the picker with the items you need from the page at time of use.